# Hiding a <div> onload and display on click event not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, echarts

I am trying to make use of the display:none and display:block on my website. The style as follows:

```
<style>
  .div_class {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

The body content is:

```
<div class="div_class">
   <div id="graph_id"></div>
</div>
```

The script is:

```
    <script>
      // some event occurs and sets the display property of div_class to block as follows
      $(".div_class").css('display','block'); 

      var BarGraph = echarts.init(document.getElementById('graph_id'), theme);
      BarGraph.setOption({  
       // properties that are set for the echart 'graph_id'
      });
    </script>
```

The `display: block;` makes the div visible but the echart properties that are set do not render. The div appears blank. What may be the reason? I am unable to figure out. Kindly help. Thanks :)

*************************** EDIT *************************************
*Also, I think the title may be misleading, since I am able to hide the div onload and display it on click. But the later rendering is where I am facing certain issue.*

Comment: Which properties are those? Can you make a snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: JavaScript is asynchronous and you display block may not happen before as expected. Also you can try to hide the content of the div and not the div itself. Visibility hidden or a more elaborate way will be with a fake loader.

Comment: *"I think the title may be misleading"* - So [edit] it to something that isn't misleading.

Comment: Does the graph appears after some time or does not appear at all?

Comment: @Rajesh It does not appear at all

Comment: @Ad33 any console errors?

Answer (score 0):

Rerender your BarGraph after showing the div

Comment: Why? OP already says their code is called in response to some event.

Comment: If you read commented part in OP's code, it says *some event occurs...* so I guess, its not happening before DOM is rendered

Comment: Some event refers to a click event on another echart graph here!

Answer (score 0):

```
 BarGraph .setOption({
```

works the same as

```
 BarGraph.setOption({
```

? (get rid of space)

also, try to wrap all your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ***code here***
});
```

Edit:

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/tutorial-en.html#Introduction%20of%20ECharts%20features%0D

^ took code from there, added jquery to head, wrapped chart block in div.container with display:none, created click event

`$(document).on('click', function() {
            $(".container").show();
            myChart.setOption(option);
        });`

working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>ECharts</title>
    <!-- including ECharts file -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://echarts.baidu.com/dist/echarts.common.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
 <style>
     .container {
      display: none;
     }
    </style>
    <!-- prepare a DOM container with width and height -->
  click anywhere!
    <div class="container">
     <div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // based on prepared DOM, initialize echarts instance
        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));

        // specify chart configuration item and data
        var option = {
            title: {
                text: 'ECharts entry example'
            },
            tooltip: {},
            legend: {
                data:['Sales']
            },
            xAxis: {
                data: ["shirt","cardign","chiffon shirt","pants","heels","socks"]
            },
            yAxis: {},
            series: [{
                name: 'Sales',
                type: 'bar',
                data: [5, 20, 36, 10, 10, 20]
            }]
        };

        // use configuration item and data specified to show chart
     $(document).on('click', function() {
      $(".container").show();
      myChart.setOption(option);
     });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry. Typing error with the space here. Thanks for pointing it out. And yes, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: This seems to be a typo otherwise the above code block would also have been not functional which set the div to block.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried with `chart.js` The chart can't be drawn if `display` property is set to `none`. The thing is `visibility:hidden` preserve the space, whereas `display:none` doesn't preserve the space

```
<style>
  .div_class{
      visibility:hidden;
  }
</style>
```

Try replacing the css with the above code. I hope this will help you :)

You can refer following post for more information: [Difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Comment: I have tried with chart.js The chart can't be drawn if the display:none is done.

Comment: Thanks for telling. :) m newbie in stackoverflow and its been only about a week that I have been using it.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <script>
      // some event occurs and sets the display property of div_class to block as follows

      $(".div_class").css('display','block').promise().done(function(){

          //draw graph here

          var BarGraph = echarts.init(document.getElementById('graph_id'), theme);
          BarGraph .setOption({  
           // properties that are set for the echart 'graph_id'
          });

      }); 


    </script>
```

Try above code. I have added .promise() What it does is only after the css "display:block;" is applied then the graph drawing process will be started